# Java - Keeping 2 keys for one value (TreeMap)

Tags: java, hashmap, treemap

I was trying to create a composite key of Type and Name both return String

```
public String getObjectName() {
    return objectName;
}
public String getObjectType() {
    return objectType;
}
```

and would like to store it in Treemap
both objectName and objectType needs to be a single key and the second String i.e value need to be a user specified Value of Type String

what are your suggestions on this?

This is where I'm gonna store the TreeMap

```
 public static void setDomainDocumentationMap(Map<String, String> domainDocumentationMap) {
    MMTUtil.domainDocumentationMap = domainDocumentationMap;
```

Comment: To construct the key from `objectName` and `objecttype` you could contatenate the values together and separate them with a separator that is not likely to occur in `objectName` or `objectType`.  For example if `objectName` is "obName" and `objecttype` is "obType" the key could be "obName-obType".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to concatenate as shown in other answers. Then you can use them as key, and in value, put whatever user input is.
This leads to `Map<String, String>` type.

Another way is to create a class for key:

```
class Key{
    private String objectName;
    private String objectType;

    //TODO write setters here

    public String getObjectName(){
        return objectName;
    }

    public String getObjectType(){
        return objectType;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return objectName + ":separator:" + objectType;
    }

    //TODO implement hashcode and equals method
}
```

Now your map should be: `Map<Key, String>` and I believe this should be more flexible.

Comment: You should also provide a hashCode() method for the Key class, which creates a hash code from objectName and objectType.

Comment: Right. Left that to implementor. `equals()` and `hashcode()` are a must.

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate the two prospective keys with a string like `"@@-#-#-@@"` or any other string which you are sure won't be there in your data, and make this concatenated string as the 'key' of your map.
In future if you need to retrieve the two key string from the 'key' of the map, just split the map's key using the `"@@-#-#-@@"` string.

Answer (score 0):

As TreeMap is ultimately a map only, It will have same structure i.e key and value.
Only thing that is different is :A tree map guarantees that its elements will be sorted in an ascending key order. You want two Strings as composite key then You can Add any separator between these two strings and then add it as a key.
For example if we use # as separator it would be **string1#string2** as key and against it there will be it's value stored.

Code Example :

```
public class Test{

    private static final String SEPERATOR ="$$" ;

    private String getCompositekey(String key1, String key2)
    {
    return key1+SEPERATOR+key2;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
    Map<String,Object> t = new TreeMap<String,Object>();
    Test test = new Test();
    t.put(test.getCompositekey(test.getObjectName(),test.getObjectType()),VALUEGOESHERE);
    }
}
```

Comment: if i'm storing 
private static final String SEPERATOR ="$$" ;

private String getCompositekey(String key1, String key2)
{
return key1+SEPERATOR+key2;
}

it in the other package and want to use getCompositKey in another class how shall I do that ?

Comment: This example is just to illustrate usage. You can use modifiers as per need. If it is in same package then keep it private else for all package access keep it public.